# Breaking dependency

Tags: java, dependency-injection

I've never studied Java in depth. Lately, I had to deal with a behaviour that I'd like to investigate, because I haven't fully understood it.

Can you explain to me why the main package does not need to import the package b? Although the the argument of aa method is B type.

This code works properly.

Can this particular case be seen as in-line dependency Injection?

```
package c;
import b.*;
public class C {
    B b=new B(); 

    public B cc(){ 
        return b; 
    }

}

package a;
import b.*; 

public class A {

    public void aa(B b) {}
}


package b; 
public class B {}



import a.A; 
import c.C; 

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        A a = new A(); 
        C c = new C();
        a.aa(c.cc()); 
        System.out.print("Test"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to import only the types you mention explicitly in the source code. When you call the `cc` method, it is already clear to the compiler which type is the return value. Imports are there only to disambiguate the mention of `B` into the fully qualified type name `b.B`.

And no, this has nothing to do with dependency injection. In that phrase, "dependency" means a runtime dependency of an object to another object and has nothing to do with compile-time dependencies between Java types.

Comment: is this a correct way to develop/design an application Or it should be avoided? Breaking compile-time dependency increase the system's flexibility? is there any pattern that express this concept?

Comment: Import statements are not there to express compile-time dependencies, if that's what you mean. I'm not sure what you mean by "this" in your question.

Comment: I could have used an object B to store the return value of cc, but this would have created a compile-time dependency between test package and B... While using the return value of the cc method as argument of aa method I avoided it!
My question is this a correct way to face this situation?

Comment: No, it didn't avoid it, the dependency is still there. All it avoids is an import statement and, as I said, import statements are not about enumerating class dependencies, but about the resolution of unqualified names.

Comment: well, if you never instantiate `C`, or involve `B` in any other way at runtime, then yes, your program will work without the `B` class present. But you didn't achieve that by making `C` not import `B`---the code can work without `B` even if there is an import statement. Import statements have (almost) nothing to do with either compile-time or runtime dependencies.